# How to detect if string contains 1 uppercase letter in PHP

Tags: php, regex, string

Couldn't find a function for this.  I'm assuming I need to use regex?

I'm trying to do html redirects in php in cases where the url contains at least 1 upper case letter.

example:  http://www.domain.com/Michael_Jordan needs to be redirected to http://www.domain.com/michael_jordan - only problem is I can't seem to find a script to detect if at least 1 capital letter exists.

Comment: @Bob: I don't see the point of doing as same as your example since DNS name are case insensitive.

Comment: It's something I was asked to do in order to improve seo - changing url site structure - past URLs had capitalized letters - so we're trying to preserve page strength from those urls while transitioning over to the new ones.

Comment: @Bob: I see, that explains it

Comment: Does Google or any search engine actually take case into account for the domain?

Comment: Not so sure about domain - but we're more worried about the trailing text in the pages.  For example, many of the urls are basketball player names, and the original links were all with First_Last format, that we're changing to first_last and apparently there is a difference there - not 100% about the domains.  http://www.wisegeek.com/are-urls-case-sensitive.htm

Comment: Makes sense for the local parts of the URL (everything after the domain), which are indeed case sensitive. If you want to rewrite those as well, the question makes sense. If it was only for the domain, I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: @Deceze: I think Bob is talking about the website structure so the approach is fine, the example was just mis leading.

Comment: Yeah - sorry about that - just changed examples in the question.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Some regular expression should be able to the work, you can use [`preg_match`](http://fr.php.net/preg_match) and `[A-Z]`

```
if(preg_match('/[A-Z]/', $domain)){
 // There is at least one upper
}
```

Comment: "There is **at least** one upper

Comment: The `+` is entirely unnecessary.

Comment: You should note that, today, domain names not only contain US letters. So this will work in must cases but not all. Ex this is a valid danish url: www.rødgrødmedFLØDE.dk

Comment: @luckydonald add the U flag to the PCRE reg exp, it should work not verified

Answer (score 35):

```
if (strtolower($url) != $url){
  //etc...
```

Comment: indeed it is simple, but isn't it overusage of strtolower?

Comment: As opposed to what? Reinventing the wheel for simple stuff like this is just dumb.

Comment: As opposed to regex, which is, imho, more semantical way to solve this issue (because the regex itself describes what we do).

Comment: Using a regex for this is a definition of overkill, not to mention overhead is quite a bit higher.

Comment: @Tyler Eaves: let's suppose you have 10mb text. `strtolower` will take a time to perform, but regex will return true on first upper-cased char occurence.

Comment: How do these two compare in terms of memory usage?  This site I'm working on gets 100K+ hits on some days so minor saves in memory usage is always a plus.

Comment: Regex will involve more memory on something like a url. Not to mention the overhead of parsing a regex, which isn't 0.

Comment: "Regex will involve more memory on something like a url" --- are you sure? http://ideone.com/OplK3

Comment: @Bob: not 0 memory the garbage collector probably collected the few bytes used. The thing is `strtolower($url) != $url`, would use twice the memory as `$url` no madder what (if we don't mess around with encoding), plus the comparison `==` might be slower than searching only for one character. After since we are talking about URL here, I think strtolower would probably performs better. If you want to be 100 % sure you might want to test it against some real url that your have on your site.  Also you have to note since you are redirecting your clients they would have to do one more network round

Comment: @Bob: trip so I don't think the 0.5 ms involved here really matters.

Comment: @Tyler Eaves: you might want to use === or strcmp here to get around php type conversions (think "0E0" and similar).

Comment: Use `mb_strtolower()` from the mbstring extension instead to make this work with non-ascii letters. Set up encodings accordingly first.

Comment: Good, but with only numbers strings like '1234' return true :(

Answer (score 7):

You can also try this

```
if (!ctype_lower($string)) {
    // there is at least une uppercase character
}
```

not sure if this is more efficient than the other two methods proposed.

Comment: I"ve felt like this is the more direct answer, by being a function that already exists in PHP.

Comment: This will work on strings that contain alphabetic characters *only*. For example, it won't work on the strings `the quick` or `noupper1`.

Answer (score 4):

```
preg_match_all('%\p{Lu}%u', 'aA,éÁ,eE,éÉ,iI,íÍ,oO,óÓ,öÖ,őŐ,uU,úÚ,üÜ,űŰ', $m);
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($m);
echo '</pre>';
```

Tested with hungarian utf-8 characters, [A-Z] is for latin1 only.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simpler eg:

```
$mydir = "C:\Users\John" ;

print preg_match('/^[A-Z]:\.*/', $mydir, $match )."\n" ;
print $match[0]. " preg match \n" ;
```

Produces:

```
1
C: preg match
```

This suggests that the parens are not necessary --for one match, at least

Look at this to be more specific for your application: [PHP to SEARCH the Upper+Lower Case mixed Words in the strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11593880/php-to-search-the-upperlower-case-mixed-words-in-the-strings)