# What's the regex code to check if there is at least 1 uppercase letter in a url? (php)

Tags: php, regex, seo

For seo purposes, I was instructed to change a line of code from something like

> http://www.Domain.com/Jimmy_Smith

to

> http://www.domain.com/jimmy_smith

What is the line of code that will detect if there is at least 1 uppercase letter in the url?

...for seo consistency.  I know regex is probably the most efficient way to do this, but I'm not very experienced with Regex.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to detect if string contains 1 uppercase letter in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4426327/how-to-detect-if-string-contains-1-uppercase-letter-in-php)

Comment: Since you always want it in lowercase, why do you need to tell if it is not lowercase, just `strtolower` it regardless, much cleaner and a single line of code.

Comment: Great point - I must have had to do this before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (preg_match('/[A-Z]/', $url)) {
    ... has one upper case char ...
} else {
    ... no uppercase chars at all ...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I would say regex is not the best way. Why not use strtolower?

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php

Comment: Because it would cause a neverending redirect loop.

Comment: parse_url(), then strtolower() the host part, then use http_build_url() to rebuild the url... it might seem like more instructions, but is cleaner than regexp.

Comment: +1 regex is expensive, avoid whenever possible and specially for small tasks.

Answer (score 1):

you don't need regex:

if a string does not equal it's lowercased self, then it has at least one uppercase char:

```
function hasUpper($x)
{
    return strtolower($x)!=$x;
}
```