# PHP to SEARCH the Upper+Lower Case mixed Words in the strings?

Tags: php, regex, search, preg-match, str-replace

Lets say there is a string like:

```
A quick brOwn FOX called F. 4lviN
```

The WORDS i want **TO SEARCH** must have the following conditions:

- The words containing MIXED Upper & Lower Cases
- Containing ONLY alphabets A to Z (A-Z a-z)
  (e.g: No numbers, NO commas, NO full-stops, NO dash .. etc)

So suppose, when i search (for e.g in this string), the search result will be:

```
brOwn
```

**Because it is the only word which contains both of Upper & Lower Case letters inside (and also containing only alphabets).**


So how can I make it work in php?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be good with:

```
preg_match_all("/\b([a-z]+[A-Z]+[a-zA-Z]*|[A-Z]+[a-z]+[a-zA-Z]*)\b/", $input, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

---

**Edit:** As capturing is not needed, it can be also >>

```
preg_match_all("/\b(?:[a-z]+[A-Z]+[a-zA-Z]*|[A-Z]+[a-z]+[a-zA-Z]*)\b/", $input, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

Comment: Perfect Ωmega !! Thats amazing regex. Since it is a interesting topic, i wonder why many people want to vote down my question. :/ Could you pls vote up it?

Comment: @Ωmega The capture group `(..)`, **and the [a-zA-Z] are redundant** and/or not necessary. That leaves `'/\b(?:[a-z]+[A-Z]+[A-z]*|[A-Z]+[a-z]+[A-z]*)\b/'` as the regex. Without capture group, the result is now found at `print_r($match[0])`.

Comment: @rubberboots - You are right, I found that right after I posted, that I don't need grouping in this case and without grouping then I should use `$matches[0]` as an output, but as it was working properly and accepted, then I let that go... But I am going to update it... Thanks.

Comment: @Ωmega - No, the grouping is necessary (but doesn't need to capture), otherwise the first `\b` applies only to the first alternative and the second `\b` applies only to the second alternative. You can get rid of the grouping but `\b` will need to occur at the beginning and end of both alternatives.

Comment: @ridgerunner - Gosh! You are right. I have edited it again. Is it now okay? Sorry everyone, I am tired today :)

Answer (score 2):

Ωmega's answer works just fine. Just for fun, here's an alternate (commented) regex that does the trick using lookahead:

```php
<?php // test.php Rev:20120721_1400
$re = '/# Match word having both upper and lowercase letters.
    \b               # Assert word begins on word boundary.
    (?=[A-Z]*[a-z])  # Assert word has at least one lowercase.
    (?=[a-z]*[A-Z])  # Assert word has at least one uppercase.
    [A-Za-z]+        # Match word with both upper and lowercase.
    \b               # Assert word ends on word boundary.
    /x';

$text ='A quick brOwn FOX called F. 4lviN';

preg_match_all($re, $text, $matches);
$results = $matches[0];
print_r($results);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a simple regular expression, such as:

```
/\s[A-Z][a-z]+\s/
```

That could be used like so:

```
preg_match_all('/\s[A-Z][a-z]+\s/', 'A quick Brown FOX called F. 4lvin', $arr);
```

Then your $arr variable which has had all the matches added to it, will contain an array of those words:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => Brown
    )

)
```

Edit: Changed the pattern.

Comment: Consider to have in input string something like `this is a bRown fOx 1Yes2 4No Maybe5 etc.`. Your code will find `Yes`, `No` and `Maybe` and none of them is a good match, but will not find `bRown` nor `fOx` which are correct matches :-/

Comment: Yes I suppose so, I didn't check that. Could always specify that the words are seperated by a whitespace character: /\s[A-Z][a-z]+\s/ Also I was assuming he meant started with an uppercase and then lowercase.

Comment: That would not work again, as you don't want to match spaces and you want to match `fOx` or `bRown`... You should edit your answer, budy...

Comment: I assume he meant started with uppercase, then the rest were lowercase, since that's the example he gave. E.g. "Brown" - YES. "bRown" - NO.

Comment: Question says "MIXED", nothing more, so there is no reason to believe he want to catch first-letter capitalized words. Regardless of that, you should still work on word boundaries, to not match spaces and not match strings like `1Yes`, `No2` or `3Maybe4`. And what is some word is on the beginning or at the end of line, with no leading or trailing spaces? Or having period after the word?

Comment: It doesn't match those... If I run that regex with for example "this is a bRown fOx 1Yes2 Brown 4No Maybe5 etc.", it will only return "Brown". Unless you're saying you think it SHOULD return 1Yes No2, etc... in which case I don't see why, as he said he didn't want any with numbers in...

Comment: You have edited your post by adding leading and trailing spaces, so no it will not match `1Yes`, `No2`, not `3Maybe4`, but it will not match `bRown` nor `fOx`. And if you will have input such `this is a test #1 Word` or `this is a test #2 Word. hello` or `Word is a test #4`, then you will miss `Word` in all cases.