# Minimum one upper character in string

Tags: php, regex, encoding, utf-8, preg-match

How can I check if string contains a minimum one uppercase character in encoding UTF-8? I checked this with `preg_match`

```
preg_match('/[A-Z]/', $var)
```

but this code doesn't work with all characters for example `Ó`, `Ł`.

How can I fix it?

Comment: @TomUdding It is likely the OP came from there since the accepted/upvoted answer there is what is being used here. The actual answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/10726645/4333555) there though that would resolve this issue has no explanation so I don't think that is a very useful dup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`A-Z` is looking between the ascii ranges. The characters you are displaying are outside of that range. Use `\p{Lu}` and use the unicode modifier `u`.

```
preg_match('/\p{Lu}/u', $var)
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/WZaOCD/1/

For more unicode options please see http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php.

Comment: Thanks! Works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the `\p{Lu}\p{Lt}` pattern too, with `unicode` flag:

```
preg_match('/[A-Z\p{Lu}\p{Lt}]/u', $var)
```

Comment: Still doesn't work :/

Comment: @polakpolkovski Sorry was a little mistake with the pattern. Try again.