# How can I find at least 1 uppercase in a string?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

In es6 js I have :

```js
good = word => {
  word.split('').includes(w => w === w.toUpperCase())
}

console.log(good('Bla'))
```

How can I return true when finding 1 Uppercase in my string?

Comment: `/[A-Z]/.test(word)`.

Comment: `includes` tests whether that function itself is literally included (which it won’t be since you’ve just created it).

Comment: If you want the index of where it is found, then use the answer I gave.

Comment: Not exact duplicate but you can use it as reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4426327/how-to-detect-if-string-contains-1-uppercase-letter-in-php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although there are much simpler ways to do this (the regex in Tushar's comment being one of them), it's possible to fix your attempt to work correctly by:

- Removing the braces so that the function actually returns a value.
- Using `.some()`, which takes a function as its argument. `.includes()` doesn't.
- Addding `const` so you're actually declaring your function.

```js
const good = word => word.split('').some(w => w === w.toUpperCase())

console.log(good('Bla'))
console.log(good('bla'))
```

Answer (score 4):

You can [test](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) the string using a regular expression with a [character set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#character-sets) of all uppercase letters `[A-Z]`:

```js
const good = word => /[A-Z]/.test(word);

console.log(good('Bla'));
console.log(good('bla'));
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do this if you want the index of it too.

```
function findUpperCase(str) {
    return str.search(/[A-Z]/);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
// The string which will go thorough the test
let theString = 'Hello World'

// Function to find out the answer
function stringCheck (receivedString) {
  // Removing special character, number, spaces from the string to perform exact output
  let stringToTest = receivedString.replace(/[^A-Z]+/ig, "")
  // Variable to count: how many uppercase characters are there in that string 
  let j = 0
  // Loop thorough each character of the string to find out if there is any uppercase available
  for (i = 0; i < stringToTest.length; i++) {
    // Uppercase character check
    if (stringToTest.charAt(i) === stringToTest.charAt(i).toUpperCase()) {
      console.log('Uppercase found: ' + stringToTest.charAt(i))
      j++
    }
  }
  console.log('Number of uppercase character: ' + j)
  // Returning the output
  if (j >= 1) {
    return true
  } else {
    return false
  }
}

// Calling the function
let response = stringCheck(theString)
console.log('The response: ' + response)
```